# Awaiting a service task gets TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

Tags: c#, windows-services, async-await, task, uwp

I have one app (UWP - Win10) and a Windows service.

The service is running in background, and they were both developed in C#. "callAsync" is the method on the service. I am using await to call it on the client.

```
var obj = await callAsync(10);
```

**The problem is:**
If this call takes less than 1min40s (100 seconds), then everything works ok. But if it takes more than 1min40s, then an exception will occur "TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled".

I have search SO and the web but still could not find any indication on how to resolve this "timeout" issue. I have added all the "open/close/receive/send" timeout flags on both app and service app.config, although the exception that is thrown in that case is different.

If I try with a simple delay in the client:

```
await Task.delay(200000);
```

it works properly.

This service was added through VS2015 "Add Service Reference". I have also "attached" to the server and the server keeps running and prints in the console before and after logs (to confirm that everything is ok).

What am I missing? What configuration and where do I need to change so that the task can run for more than 1 minute and 40 seconds?

**CODE:**

**Example of Server Pseudo-Code:**

*Interface File:*

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://.....")]
interface ICom {

   [OperationContract]
   int call(int val);

}
```

*Service.cs*

```
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    public BlaBlaWindowsService()
    {
        ServiceName = "BlaBlaWindowsService";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new BlaBlaWindowsService());
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BlaBlaService));

        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "BlaBlaWindowsService";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
```

*BlaBlaService.cs*

```
class TPAService : ITPAComunication {

   public int call(int val) {

      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200000)
      return 0;
   }

}
```

*App.config file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<binding name="ServiceTimeout" closeTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"/>
</bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="BlaBla.Service.Service"
                   behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/BlaBla/service"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="ServiceTimeout"
                      contract="BlaBla.Service.ICom" />
            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

**Example of App pseudo-code:**

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress epa = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/blabla/service");

System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding bhb = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();

Timespan t = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

bhb.SendTimeout = t; bhb.ReceiveTimeout =t; bhb.OpenTimeout = t; bhb.CloseTimeout = t;

Blabla.ComunicationClient com = new Blabla.ComunicationClient(bhb, epa);

var obj = await com.callAsync(int val);

return obj;
```

**UPDATE #1**

This situation only happens in UWP. I have created a similar WinForms project and everything works as expected. This means that it is probably something related to UWP.

Comment: This probably happens because of a timeout in the web request:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Bas Thanks for the comment, but a Timeout (according to the documentation you just linked, throws a WebException. The case I am mentioning throws a TaskCanceledException. (In Linked Docs: "If the resource is not returned within the time-out period, the request throws a WebException")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries, manipulating different config files, I have not found a solution regarding how to remove the timeout limitation of 100 seconds. To solve this specific problem, I implemented a counter-measure.

**What I have found during my tries was:**

- If the project is in WinForms, everything works as expected. This means, this 100-second-limit, is an UWP "Feature";
- If you reduce the SendTimeout to less than 100 seconds, it will throw a TimeoutException with the corresponding timer;
- This is not exclusive to the Windows Service. It also happens when comunicating with a SOAP Webservice implementation;
- This seems to happen only if you are doing a task the requires "external communication" with a service reference. If you have a "internal" task that takes more than 100 seconds, it works as expected (eg. await Task.delay(250000)).

**How I solved this?**

After chatting at C# SO channel, @Squiggle suggested a polling approach and that is what I implemented and tested successfully.

These are the steps I took:

1. I updated the existing service request (call(int val)) to accept a another argument, a Guid, so I could identify which request I wanted to do the "polling";
2. I created an additional request at the service to InquireAboutCurrentRequest that accepted also accepted a GUID parameter, and returned an int;
3. I updated the Service Reference at the UWP app with the new request;
4. I called "await call(val,guid)" with a try catch. I did this because 90% of these calls return in less than 30 seconds*;
5. In the catch I added an "If" that checked if the exception was a CancelTask, and if was I call "await InquireAboutCurrentRequest(guid)";
6. This method, at the windows service, keeps checking if the other operation has ended and sleeps every X seconds. Since the total time of the first call can only be at most 2 minutes, I only need to wait 20 seconds;
7. After that I will deal with the result accordingly, but at least this time I know I have "waited 2 minutes" for the response.

There are other possible solutions such as sockets, which I have not tried, that could work.

***** If all the requests take more than 100 seconds, I suggest using the polling approach from the beginning of the requests, instead of waiting for the try/catch.

Comment: It is polling not pooling. To "Poll" means to ask repeatedly, to "Pool" is to use a group of resources which individual requests remove from the group then return the resource to the group when done. Both words are used frequently in programming so it is important to use the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly - but may be better use [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of await ?

Comment: It still throws a Task Cancelled exception for the task that is communicating with the service.